# How to find similar image on google

Tags: images

I have an image and i want to find the similar image and edit it. Is there any way to find the similar image as vector or png or jpg . The below is what im finding

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want this image as a jpg, you already have it?

Comment: @Ryan i want to edit that date so i want to find a vector file and edit it

Comment: I doubt this image exists in vector format. If you're working for these people, ask them for the original files that this was created with

Comment: @ZachSaucier after removing the background in photoshop i just want to add the cut line or border line around the image to print on tshirt

Comment: Do you actually want a similar image or *that exact image*?

Comment: If you want free SVG vector files of skulls, have a look on openclipart(dot)org.

Comment: So you're just going to snaggle & print someone else's design on a t-shirt? Cool story

Comment: @cai actually i want to delete the black background and a pink color stroke of 1 i need around the image

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to search for a particular image, or similar versions, on the web.
Google has a "reverse image search" and the website tineye does also.

Neither of them found any results for your skull image.

When you're image does return results and you're looking for a vector version then look over the results for vector file types: .png (close enough) .pdf, .ai. svg etc.

Comment: yeah i have search but did not find nothing

Comment: If google doesn't see it then the image probably doesn't exist online. You can do a google image search for something like "skull .png" and find other results which you can edit. If its a .jpg or other raster file types you cannot easily edit it.

Comment: the problem is i can remove the background with single click photoshop but i want the cut line to print from vinyl print on tshirt how can i make cut line

Comment: @ateks You'll want to browse for this in our questions or ask a new question as they are they different things.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you can right click the image and click "Search Google for image".

Not in Chrome, you can use [Google's image search page](https://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl) and upload the image or enter the URL of it.

Alternatively (perhaps more convenient if you do this a lot and don't use Chrome), you can install a [browser extension](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+search+for+image+extension&rlz=1C1ASUT_en-GBAU463AU463&oq=google+search+for+image+extension&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.4411j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

---

To only get results of a certain file type, enter `filetype:SVG` or whatever file type you want.

---

If you're unable to find the image this way, it probably doesn't exist online in a Google-searchable format. You can try describing the image to find similar things. An example description of this image may be "Mike N Kayla wedding invite", "skull wedding invitation black", etc.

Comment: yeah i have search but did not find nothing